# Change on hover and on focus class after masked input js was added

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have added jQuery-Mask-Plugin and everything works fine but after I have added it I can't style my input field.

Here what I get:

Input form:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="phone">Enter your phone number</label>
    <input type="phone" class="form-control phone" id="phone" aria-describedby="set Phone">
</div>
```

and here is standard on focus style that works great if I don't use this js

```
.order-form input[type='phone']:focus {border: 1px solid #345564; color: #345564;}
```

So then I create js file:

```
$(function(){$('#phone').mask('+7(000) 000-0000');});
```

So, problem is that now, after I added this js and linked [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

and my text color is white not blue one.

Could you help me to show how I can stye this text?

Comment: Can you share a live example, this so i can try to debug it

Comment: Playing in there site, i can style any mask they got going

Comment: Sure, http://blackpolygon.ru/test/signin_phys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your site you have the next html

```
<input type="email" class="form-control phone" id="phone" aria-describedby="Укажите номер" maxlength="16" style="color: rgb(99, 99, 99);">
```

As you can see, you have the inline style grey color for you text.

To solve your problem you can use the `important` tag or remove that inline style that has a bigger priority than you css style.

Example using `!important`

```
.order-form input[type='email']:focus {
  border: 1px solid #345564;
  color: #345564!important;
}
```

Note: `!important` tag isn't the best practice. Use it with care.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, i have found the problem. You were right. But additional problem was that i used Phone tag before and my js added css class to white. So it works fine now. Thanks